# Голоустненский или Голоустнинский тракт?

Tags: орфография

Есть населенный пункт *"Большое Голоустное"*. Как правильно: "Мы едем по Голоустн**е**нскому тракту" или "Мы едем по Голоустн**и**нскому тракту"?

Answer (score 3):

Полагаю, название тракта - зафиксированное в источниках имя собственное. На карте Иркутской области  это **ГолоустнЕнский тракт** ([карта здесь](http://maps.yandex.ru/?text=%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%98%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%2C%20%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82&sll=104.428056%2C52.271621&ll=104.424516%2C52.271935&spn=0.038924%2C0.020219&z=15&l=map))

Answer (score 2):

У Розенталя есть четкое правило: "Имена прилагательные, образованные от географических названий, оканчиваются:
а) на -инский, если они образованы от названий на -и (Грязи - грязинский) и на -а (-я) Балашиха - балашихинский, но: Пенза - пензенский, Пресня - пресненский;
б) на -енский , если они образованы от названий других типов (Заречье - зареченский, Песочная - песоченский). Вывод: Голустное - Голустненский тракт